# Routing optional parameters with Http.RouteAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have an action with two required and a few optional parameters:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetUsers(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, string zipcode, int? countryId)
{
    using (DataHandler handler = new DataHandler())
        return Ok(handler.GetUsers(dateFrom, dateTo).ToList());
}
```

I want an url like this one:

```
/api/getusers/2018-12-03T07:30/2018-12-03T12:45?zipcode=4002&countryId=4
```

`zipcode` and `countryId` are optional and will be added with the `?`-thingy. The required parameters `dateFrom` and `dateTo` will be added with `/`

so following urls should be possible too:

```
/api/getusers/2018-12-03T07:30/2018-12-03T12:45?countryId=4
/api/getusers/2018-12-03T07:30/2018-12-03T12:45?zipcode=4002
/api/getusers/2018-12-03T07:30/2018-12-03T12:45
```

I tried a few routings like

```
[Route("getusers/{dateFrom}/{dateTo}")]
[Route("getusers/{dateFrom}/{dateTo}*")]
[Route("getusers/{dateFrom}/{dateTo}**")]
[Route("getusers/{dateFrom}/{dateTo}?zipcode={zipcode}&countryId={countryId}")]
```

but none of them are working. 
When I remove the optional parameters it works, but I need those optional ones.

Any idea how to get this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the optional parameters optional in the action method

> If a route parameter is optional, you must define a default value for the method parameter.

```
//GET /api/getusers/2018-12-03T07:30/2018-12-03T12:45?countryId=4
//GET /api/getusers/2018-12-03T07:30/2018-12-03T12:45?zipcode=4002
//GET /api/getusers/2018-12-03T07:30/2018-12-03T12:45
[HttpGet]
[Route("getusers/{dateFrom:datetime}/{dateTo:datetime}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetUsers(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, string zipcode = null, int? countryId = null) {
    using (DataHandler handler = new DataHandler())
        return Ok(handler.GetUsers(dateFrom, dateTo).ToList());
}
```

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)